# What is a space-efficient way to display two numbers next to each other while minimising confusion?

Tags: web, header, visual-cues

I'm working on a site that needs to show two balances next to each other, preferably in the header next to a user's name. The issue I'm having is differentiating the balances enough that they don't get confused or cluttered.

The two number balances are:

- Giving (Ex. 3,000)
- Received (Ex. 10,000)

Does anyone have any clever ideas how to distinguish these while saving space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is actually found here, on UX.SE. If you look at your name at the top of the page, you'll notice four different counts [Reputation points, No of Gold badges, No of Silver badges and No of Bronze badges].

[image: UX.SE user and status]

If you apply the same to your app, it could look like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f35hHh.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

a plus(+) sign would represent received, and a minus (-) sign would represent giving. You could also use colors, if you find some appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Default signs in most finance systems are arrow indicators: red down arrow for spent and green up arrow for received money. So it is the clearest way to represent balances using such signs, for instance in such compact way:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffiZoc.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>